# Regular Expression for Network Interface selection

Tags: python, regex

I need help on finding the Interfaces alone using regex.

```
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 152.135.2.2 255.255.255.255
!
interface Port-channel1
 description *** 2 port Etherchannel to ic***
 switchport
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet1
 vrf forwarding mgmtVrf
 no ip address
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet3/1
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!
interface Vlan42
 ip address 10.2.2.3 255.255.255.240
 standby 42 ip 10.2.2.31
 standby 42 priority 105
 standby 42 preempt
!
interface GigabitEthernet6/48
 description ***connected to Panel***
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet7/1
!
```

I am trying to use the below syntax however, its showing all the interfaces information which doesnt match

```
"^((?!Ten|Vlan|Loopback|Port).)*$"
```

I am looking for the below result.

```
interface FastEthernet1
interface GigabitEthernet6/4
interface GigabitEthernet7/1
```

Comment: Do you need only those 3 lines? `interface FastEthernet1
interface GigabitEthernet6/4
interface GigabitEthernet7/1`
 If it is the case just use: `^interface\s*(?=Fast|Giga).*` site:https://regex101.com/r/qiqcl9/1, also could you specify the language?

Comment: Thanks allan for your prompt response. Yes I need only those lines. I am using Python. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have added an answer in order for you to accept/vote up ;-) Great that I could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the 3 lines:

```
interface FastEthernet1
interface GigabitEthernet6/4
interface GigabitEthernet7/1
```

Then you can use the following regex:

```
^interface\s*(?=Fast|Giga).*
```

have a look at : 
https://regex101.com/r/qiqcl9/1